# A person who does everything so slowly

Tags: word-usage, word-request

What do you usually call someone who usually does anything so slowly that sometimes it can even get on someone's nervs?

We call such a person a "slow-motion" and say:

> - He's a reall slow-motion!

How would you convey the same message?

Added: in my language this word can be attributed to the person either in a humorous way or sarcastically; even to somebody who walks so slowly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a word that can be used to describe such a person: [**slowpoke**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/slowpoke).

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : a very slow person
>   // We're going to be late if that *slowpoke* doesn't hurry up.
>   // quit being such a *slowpoke* this morning, or you'll be late

I can't think of a context in which it wouldn't be used in at least a somewhat negative way.

Comment: In British English, it would be a slowcoach or slow-coach. A sluggard is a somewhat formal term.